# How do I convert part of an Excel file to a reduced DataSet in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import, dataset

I have one Excel document with multiple Worksheets.

I have uploaded and converted the file to a `DataTable` object using the code below:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(SourceUpload.Fullpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); //xlsx file format
ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

This code converts the whole file if 100000 rows are available, but I want the DataSet to contain a subset of this data (1000 rows and 1000 columns).

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Comment: I recall there being a way to select a subset of data via SQL when importing an Excel file into a DataSet by using an ODBC connection. This is probably an ideal solution for you. I will have a look through my codebase to see if I can find a solution for you. In the meantime, could you provide an example Excel file with multiple Worksheets and an example of how you want the resulting DataSet to look?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of some `Linq` to achieve this. So something like:

```
DataTable dt = //get data from excel or wherever
IEnumerable<DataRow> data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a).Take(1000);//Select everything but only take the top 1000 records
DataTable someTable = data.CopyToDataTable(); //copy the data 

//finally add it to our data set
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(someTable);
```

Please note the above snippet is from the top of my head and I've not tested it.

Comment: above code.i have converts excel file with more than 5laksh rows below exception occurs.                                                                          Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: @RajaGanapathy Can you provide a sample of how your excel file looks like